# POI Java to convert xlsx to CSV comma and double quotes

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

Trying to convert xlsx to CSV, where one column has multiple quotes and comma, when converting to CSV, it is separated to different cells instead of one cell. 
Below is scenario,

[image: Actual Data]

[image: Converted]

The Title is moving to multiple, attaching the code

```
if(cell.getStringCellValue().contains(",")){
              if (cell.getStringCellValue().contains("\"")){
                                String t= "\""+cell.getStringCellValue()+"\"";
                                data.append(t+",");
                                }
                                else{
                                data.append("\""+cell.getStringCellValue()+"\""+",");
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Why not just use one of the many properly written and tested open source CSV libraries, which does the escaping right, rather than trying to roll your own badly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape these special signs:

eg. if you want to have values `one` and `two,three` as two columns in a CSV file enclose the second column in quotes:

```
one,"two,three"
```

To escape double quotes `"` in the column value encolse it with double quotes and use `""` to escape the quotes inside the value. eg if you have a field with `abc"def` it should be escaped as:

```
"abc""def"
```

So for your case it could be one liner instead of the whole `if` statement:

```
data.append("\"").append(cell.getStringCellValue().replaceAll("\"", "\"\"")).append("\",");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My case is Like below,                                                                "BESPI: Scheduled metric collection has failed for task "bespi_start bespi_mon.pl -m 600,609" and user "$AGENT_USER".  [Policy: BESPI_Collect_Router_5m]","P3"

Comment: @VICKY-TSC I've updated my answer with solution for you.